# Sprockets::Rails::Environment::NoDigestError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

When I try to access to the contents the assets/application.css through the following URL
this warning is triggered. I am using rails 4.2 beta 
In old versions of Rails I could to access to the contents of the public folder

localhost:3000/assets/application.css

```
   Sprockets::Rails::Environment::NoDigestError
    Assets should not be requested directly without their digests: Use the helpers in ActionView::Helpers to request application.css

   path = path.sub("-#{fingerprint}", '')
          else
            raise NoDigestError.new(path)
          end

          asset = find_asset(path)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem was in this line config.assets.digest = true . I edited this line in config/enviroments/development to config.assets.digest = false and worked

Comment: What about in production?